# Tkinter keeps generating duplicate groups

Tags: python, tkinter

Writing a script to make 3-4 person groups from a list of up to 12. It generates the groups but keeps duplicating the groups 1 group without the buttons and 1 group with the buttons for each group. Any ideas?

Makes groups as

Group 1
1
2
3
4

Group 1
1 b b b b
2 b b b b
3 b b b b
4 b b b b

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import random

class TournamentApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Tournament App")
        self.geometry("800x600")
        
        self.participants = []
        self.rounds = 0
        self.pairings = []
        self.results = {}
        
        self.entry_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.entry_frame.pack(pady=10)
        self.entry_frame.place(x=100, y=25)
        
        self.round_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.round_frame.pack(pady=10)
        
        self.round_label = tk.Label(self.round_frame, text="Round 1")
        self.round_label.pack()
        
        self.results_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.results_frame.pack(pady=10)
        self.results_frame.place(x=1100, y=25)
        
        self.results_label = tk.Label(self.results_frame, text="Results")
        self.results_label.pack()
        
        self.win_loss_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.win_loss_frame.pack(pady=10)
        
        self.create_entry_fields()
        self.create_pairings_button()
        self.create_round_button()
        self.create_results_table()
        self.create_bracket_label()
        self.create_bracket_frames()
        self.create_reset_button()

    def create_entry_fields(self):
        entry_label = tk.Label(self.entry_frame, text="Enter participant names:")
        entry_label.place(x=400, y=100)
        entry_label.pack()
        
        for i in range(12):
            entry = tk.Entry(self.entry_frame)
            entry.pack(pady=5)
            self.participants.append(entry)
            
    def create_pairings_button(self):
        pairings_button = tk.Button(self, text="Generate Pairings", command=self.generate_pairings)
        pairings_button.pack(pady=10)
        
    def create_round_button(self):
        round_button = tk.Button(self, text="Start New Round", command=self.start_new_round)
        round_button.pack(pady=10)
        
    def create_results_table(self):
        self.results_table = tk.Label(self.results_frame, text="")
        self.results_table.pack()
        
    def create_bracket_label(self):
        bracket_label = tk.Label(self, text="Generated Pairings")
        bracket_label.pack()
        
    def create_bracket_frames(self):
        self.bracket_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.bracket_frame.pack(pady=10)
        
        self.bracket_frames = []
        
        for i in range(4):
            frame = tk.Frame(self.bracket_frame)
            frame.grid(row=i, column=0, padx=10)
            self.bracket_frames.append(frame)
        
    def generate_pairings(self):
        participants_copy = self.participants.copy()  # Create a copy of the participants list
        self.shuffle_participants()
        self.pair_participants()
        self.participants = participants_copy  # Restore the original participants list
        self.update_brackets()
        self.create_placement_buttons()
        self.rounds = 1


    def shuffle_participants(self):
        shuffled_participants = self.participants.copy()
        random.shuffle(shuffled_participants)
        self.participants = shuffled_participants

        
    def pair_participants(self):
        min_players_per_group = 4
        max_players_per_group = 4

        num_players = len(self.participants)
        if num_players < min_players_per_group:
            messagebox.showwarning("Insufficient Players", "At least {} players are required.".format(min_players_per_group))
            return

        self.pairings = []
        group_pairing = []

        for i, participant in enumerate(self.participants):
            if participant.get().strip():  # Ignore empty entry fields
                group_pairing.append(participant)

            if len(group_pairing) == max_players_per_group or i == num_players - 1:
                self.pairings.append(group_pairing)
                group_pairing = []

    # Add the remaining participants to the last group if it's not empty
        if group_pairing:
            self.pairings.append(group_pairing)

    def update_brackets(self):
        for frame in self.bracket_frames:
            for widget in frame.winfo_children():
                widget.destroy()
        
        for i, pairing in enumerate(self.pairings):
            frame = self.bracket_frames[i]
            label = tk.Label(frame, text="Group {}".format(i+1), font=("Arial", 12, "bold"))
            label.pack()
            
            for j, participant in enumerate(pairing):
                entry_frame = tk.Frame(frame)
                entry_frame.pack()
                
                label = tk.Label(entry_frame, text=participant.get(), width=20)
                label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        
    def start_new_round(self):
        #self.generate_pairings() #call to generate new pairings on new round trigger
        if self.rounds > 0:
            self.update_results_table()
            
        self.rounds += 1
        self.round_label.config(text="Round {}".format(self.rounds))
        
    def record_placement(self, group_index, player_index, placement):
        group_pairing = self.pairings[group_index]
        participant = group_pairing[player_index].get()
        
        if participant not in self.results:
            self.results[participant] = {
                "1st Place": 0,
                "2nd Place": 0,
                "3rd Place": 0,
                "4th Place": 0
            }
        
        if placement == 1:
            self.results[participant]["1st Place"] += 1
        elif placement == 2:
            self.results[participant]["2nd Place"] += 1
        elif placement == 3:
            self.results[participant]["3rd Place"] += 1
        elif placement == 4:
            self.results[participant]["4th Place"] += 1
        
        self.update_results_table()
        
    def update_results_table(self):
        results_text = "Results after Round {}:\n\n".format(self.rounds)
        
        for participant, data in self.results.items():
            results_text += "{}: 1st Place: {}, 2nd Place: {}, 3rd Place: {}, 4th Place: {}\n".format(
                participant, data["1st Place"], data["2nd Place"], data["3rd Place"], data["4th Place"]
            )
        
        self.results_table.config(text=results_text)

    def create_placement_buttons(self):
        for i, pairing in enumerate(self.pairings):
            frame = self.bracket_frames[i]
            group_label = tk.Label(frame, text="Group {}".format(i+1), font=("Arial", 12, "bold"))
            group_label.pack()
            
            for j, participant in enumerate(pairing):
                entry_frame = tk.Frame(frame)
                entry_frame.pack()
                
                label = tk.Label(entry_frame, text=participant.get(), width=20)
                label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
                
                options = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]
                clicked = tk.StringVar()
                clicked.set("First")
                
                drop = tk.OptionMenu(entry_frame, clicked, *options)
                drop.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
                
                button = tk.Button(entry_frame, text="Record Placement", command=lambda group_index=i, player_index=j: self.record_placement(group_index, player_index, options.index(clicked.get()) + 1))
                button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    def create_reset_button(self):
        reset_button = tk.Button(self, text="Reset", command=self.reset)
        reset_button.place(x=10, y=10)
        
    def reset(self):
        self.participants = []
        self.rounds = 0
        self.pairings = []
        self.results = {}
        
        for frame in self.bracket_frames:
            for widget in frame.winfo_children():
                widget.destroy()
        
        self.round_label.config(text="Round 1")
        self.results_table.config(text="")
        
        for entry in self.entry_frame.winfo_children():
            entry.destroy()

        self.create_entry_fields()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TournamentApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Kept trying to change the generate.pairings method and the shuffle.participants. No real change.

It is supposed to be

Group 1
1 b b b b
2 b b b b
3 b b b b
4 b b b b

Comment: Can you reduce the size of your code? It seems like there's a lot of code there that isn't necessary to reproduce the problem. The code still needs to be runnable, but we only need just enough code to reproduce the problem. See [mcve].

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The first set without buttons is generated by `update_brackets()` and the second set with buttons is generated by `create_placement_buttons()`.

Simply remove the for loop inside `update_brackets()`:

```py
def update_brackets(self):
    for frame in self.bracket_frames:
        for widget in frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
```

Also there is logic bug in `pair_participants()` that an empty list will be appended into `self.pairings` sometimes. Below is the modified `pair_participants()` to fix the issue:

```py
def pair_participants(self):
    min_players_per_group = 4
    max_players_per_group = 4

    num_players = len(self.participants)
    if num_players < min_players_per_group:
        messagebox.showwarning("Insufficient Players", "At least {} players are required.".format(min_players_per_group))
        return

    self.pairings = []
    group_pairing = []

    for i, participant in enumerate(self.participants):
        if participant.get().strip():  # Ignore empty entry fields
            group_pairing.append(participant)

            ### this if statement should be within the above if statement
            if len(group_pairing) == max_players_per_group:
                self.pairings.append(group_pairing)
                group_pairing = []

    # Add the remaining participants to the last group if it's not empty
    if group_pairing:
        self.pairings.append(group_pairing)
```